# Objective-c remove table view when no data present to show

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

Currently in my app, when there is no data to show in my table view it shows a very tall white space and I would like that gone.

I need a way to programatically change the height to 0 or hide the view entirely from the layout flow (so it doesn't affect other UI components while there is no data). Seems no matter what approach I have taken that I have this ugly tall white space. I can only assume its because I have a height constraint on the table to be 500. I have tried to remove this programatically with no luck and just need some help.

My code:

```
if([theData count] <= 0) {    
    CGRect frame = self.ScrollView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 0;
    self.TableView.frame = frame;
}
```

I have also tried:

```
if([theData count] <= 0) {    
    self.TableView = nil
}
```

and a number of other silly things not worth mentioning. Can anyone give me a hand here? I mostly just want the entire table gone when there is no data.

Comment: do you have any control below tableview? If no then simply set alpha 0 & userinteraction NO for tableview.

Comment: I do :( , below the table I have a link to a view that shows an "all listing" of that data object. The one I am trying to hide only show the most recent 4 or 5.

Comment: ok do like this way- 
  
    if (self.yourArray.count ==0)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.myTable.frame = CGRectZero;
        });
    }

Comment: Or what about - if (theData.count <= 0) { self.TableView.hidden = true; } 
have you tried this?

Comment: @IceCode I did try that, the hidden (I assume anyway) works like hiding something in a web browser who's component is still affecting the DOM. I want the height to be gone and the white space to be gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already mentioned that you have a height constraint on TableView which is set to 500. Create a `IBOutlet` of tableView's height constraint lets say `tableViewHeightConstraint`. Finally in order to set the frame of tableView height to 0 u can make use of `didSet` method of your data source

```
var theData : [whatever_your_data_type] {
    didSet {
        if theData.count == 0 {
            self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
            self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
        else {
            if self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant == 0 {
                self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = 500
                self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Code in Objective-C**

Write the setter to your array. If your array name is theData,

```
-(void)setTheData:(NSMutableArray *)theData {
    if(self.theData.count == 0) {
        self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0;
        [self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];
    }
    else {
        if(self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant == 0) {
            self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = 500;
            [self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Step 1: Open your xib/storyboard which contains the tableView.

Step 2: Select the tableViewHeight constraint in xib/storyBoard

Step 3: Now control drag from height constraint to the viewController which owns the tableView

[image]

The logic of using setter of the array to decide whether to show tableView or not is the logic I wanted to convey. You can use this logic to hide the tableView/set the frame to 0/set the height constraint to 0 or whatever you wanna use :)

Comment: I agree more with this approach, OP should modify a height constraint instead of just setting its whole frame to 0.

Comment: @nsgangster : Thank u :)

Comment: can you write this in OBJ-C for me please? I am not writing in swift

Comment: @goredefex : Gimme a minute

Comment: @SandeepBhandari thank you so much. The only thing I don't fully understand is how you set a constraint as an IBOutlet. That confuses me a lot. Any links you can post or help you can give?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for your array count & put your table rect to Zero as below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.array =[NSMutableArray array];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    if (self.array.count ==0)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.myTable.frame = CGRectZero;
        });
    }
}
```

I have written the code in viewDidLoad. You can place where you want in your code.